# Code from beforeEach running after the 'it'spec

Tags: mocha.js, bdd, supertest

I'm using mocha and supertest to test a REST service. In this case, I need to test that a subsequent login after a GET request returns the query from that GET request.

1. login user
2. perform GET request on endpoint(s) using params
3. login user and expect params from GET request as a response.

Since the above test is going to be performed several times for various endpoints, this is what I have come up with:

```
/*
 * getRequest.js
 */
'use strict';

var request = require('supertest')
    , verifyUrl = require('./verifyUrl') // verifies basic url formatting
    ;

module.exports = getRequest;

/**
 * Perform GET request using given parameters and call next when finished.
 * @param getEnvironment {json}
 * @param getEnvironment.url {string}
 * @param getEnvironment.endPoint {string}
 * @param getEnvironment.authorization {string}
 * @param next {function} The callback
 */
function(getEnvironment, getParams, next) {
    var url = verifyUrl(getEnvironment.url);
    request(url)
        .get(getEnvironment.endPoint)
        .set("authorization", getEnvironment.authorization)
        .set('Accept', 'application/json')
        .query(getParams)
        .end(next)
}
```

---

```
/*
 * loginWithCallback.js
 * 
 * Performs a basic login but depends on the callback to test the results of the login.
 */
'use strict';

var request = require('supertest')
    , VerifyUrl = require('./VerifyUrl')
    ;

module.exports = LoginWithCallback;

/**
 * Perform basic login, then call next passing in err and res for testing.
 *
 * @param setEnvironment {json}  Expects url and authorization. Any other parameters will be ignored.
 * @param setEnvironment.url {string} The url being tested.
 * @param setEnvironment.authorization {string} 
 * @param next {function} callback function that will perform the actual test.
 */
function LoginWithCallback(setEnvironment, next) {

    var url = VerifyUrl(setEnvironment.url);

    request(url)
        .post('api/users/login')
        .set('authorization', setEnvironment.authorization)
        .set('Accept', 'application/json')
        .end(next);
}
```

---

```
/*
 * e2eTest.js
 */
'use strict';

var base64_encode = require('Base64').btoa
    , should = require('should')
    , jsonValidator = require('is-my-json-valid')
    , mergeJSON = require('lodash/merge')
    , lodashClone = require('lodash/clone')
    , responseSchema = require('./responseSchemas/200.json')
    , login = require('./loginWithCallback')
    , getRequest = require('./getRequest')
    ;

var username = "newUser" + Date.now()
    , password = "passW0rd"
    , testEnvironment = {
        "url": "http://localhost:9000/",
        "endPoint": "api/users/login",
        "authorization": "Basic " + base64_encode(username + ":" + password)
    }
    ;

var expectedResult = {};

describe('End to End testing on' + JSON.stringify(testEnvironment), function () {
    describe('new user, ' + username + ', login', function () {
        it('should return 200 and an empty body message.', function (done) {
            login(testEnvironment, function (err, res) {
                if (err) {
                    done(err);
                }

                res.statusCode.should.deepEqual(200);

                var jsonValidate = jsonValidator(responseSchema, {verbose: true});
                jsonValidate(res.body).should.be.true("Response body failed schema check: \n" +
                    JSON.stringify(jsonValidate.errors, null, 4));

                res.body.should.deepEqual(expectedResult);

                done();
            });
        });
    });


    describe('user, ' + username + ', logs in after performing get request', function () {
        var getRequestParams = {"firstName":"john", "lastName":"doe"};

        beforeEach(function() {
            var getEnviron = lodashClone(testEnvironment);
            getEnviron.endPoint = 'api/persons/findName';
            mergeJSON(expectedResult, {"persons": {"findName": getRequestParams}});
            getRequest(getEnviron, getReqestParams, function(err, res) {
                if (err) {
                    done(err);
                }
                console.log("GET request: " JSON.stringify(res, null, 2));
                done();
            });
        });

        it('should return 200 and query values', function(done) {
             login(testEnvironment, function (err, res) {
             if (err) {
                 done(err)
             }

             console.log("it test: " + JSON.stringify(res, null, 2));

             res.statusCode.should.deepEqual(200);

             var jsonValidate = jsonValidator(responseSchema, {verbose: true});
             jsonValidate(res.body).should.be.true("Response body failed schema check: \n" + JSON.stringify(jsonValidate.errors, null, 4));

             res.body.should.deepEqual(expectedResult);

             done();

        });
    });
});
```

What the above three files are supposed to do is the following:
1. create a new user
2. login new user and test its response for no previous query params. (passes)
3. perform the GET request and then print the result in the before block
4. perform the login of the user print and test results in the it block.

But what I'm getting is something like:

```
End to End testing on{"url":"http://localhost:9000/","endPoint":"api/users/login","authorization":"Basic bmV3VXNlcjE0NjY0NDI0OTEzNDc6cGFzc1cwcmQ="}
  new user, newUser1466442491347, login
    ✓ should return 200 and an empty body message. (54ms)

  user, newUser1466442491347, logs in after performing persons/findByName request
it test: [res text]
    1) should return and query values
GET request: [res text]

1 passing
1 failing

     Uncaught AssertionError: expected Object {} to equal Object {
  persons: Object { findByName: Object { firstName: 'joe', lastName: 'jones' } }
 }
```

As can be seen, the 'it' block is appearing to run before the before block has finished.  From my reading of mocha, this should not happen as it waits for the before and beforeEach finishes before running the 'it' block.  But, perhaps, the callback for the getRequest gets queued after the it block?

What am I doing wrong or misunderstanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely **must** set your `beforeEach` hook so that Mocha knows it is asynchronous: either you return a promise to Mocha or you use the `done` callback. In order to use the `done` callback you must declare a callback that takes `done`:

```
beforeEach(function (done) {
```

(You could call it anything you want (e.g. `finished`), so long as you are consistent (call `finished()` later).)

Comment: Was the last codeblock in my question not sufficient? `getRequest(getEnvironment, getRequestParams, function(err, res) { done(); });` However, realizing that I don't properly handle err, I modified it as follows (which excludes `res` since I don't use it): `getRequest(getEnvironment, getRequestParams, function(err) { if (err) { done(err); } done(); });`

(or see edit in the above question)

Comment: @Machtyn No, it was not sufficient. For one thing, as you yourself point out here, you did not handle `err`. It may very well be the case that once things execute in the proper order, an error is revealed. Also, well, I've answered enough questions about Mocha to know that some people get *really* confused about where `done` should be declared, which is something you did not show in your question. (No, really: some people forget to declare it, or declare it in the wrong place.) Also, it is unsafe to have `mergeJSON` after `getRequest`. Unclear whether it would be a factor here, but still.

Comment: I'll gladly delete this answer once you edit your question to have it show what it should have shown in the first place. As I said, you **must** tell Mocha that your hook is asynchronous. So the code you show initially for your hook (without `done`) is just flat out wrong. There's no point even in showing it because you do have a better version of your code: the version that uses `done`. You should edit the question to show exactly the hook you run with `done`, and explain what behavior you get *when you run this code*.

Comment: Ok, with your edit now the issue is that you indeed did not declare `done`. I've edited my answer.

Comment: I've edited the question to include the improved code in the getRequest call and moved the mergeJSON to the before the getRequest. Unfortunately, I'm getting the same result. Perhaps, I am doing something wrong somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks! I knew to declare it as part of `it('...', function(done){})`, but did not know about it for `before(function(done){})`.